# Not able to set the user name and password for SQL Authentication

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have installed the sql server management studio 2008.I did not get any field for setting the username and password while installing.After installing i tried to alter the password of "sa" but below error coming

Change password failed for Login 'sa'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

"An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.

Cannot alter the login 'sa', because it does not exist or you do not have permission. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15151)

ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.00.2531&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=15151&LinkId=20476"

I want to access the sql in sql authentication mode .

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the login page-

In your server name: yourcomputername\SQLEXPRESS

And authentication name should be: Windows Authentication

Now your user name and passward should be disabled and the computer name should be there.

Comment: i can enter through windows authentication but i cannot set the password for sql authentication.